# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \big[ \frac{1}{a_{1}a_{2}}+\frac{1}{a_{2}a_{3}}+...+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}a_{n}}\big]$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $a_{1}=1$, $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+4, \ \forall n \geq 2$ then what is $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \big[ \frac{1}{a_{1}a_{2}}+\frac{1}{a_{2}a_{3}}+...+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}a_{n}}\big]$$

Using recurrence relations I obtained $a_{n} =1+(n-1)4, \ \forall n \geq 2$ but then substituting it in the above limit didn't help me much.

Can anyone suggest what should be done? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Note:
$$
\frac{1}{a_{n-1}a_n}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{4}{a_{n-1}a_{n}}=\frac{1}{4}\Big(\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{a_n}\Big)
$$
The last equality uses the fact that $a_n-a_{n-1}=4$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: yeah, thank you